# Syntax of for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, syntax

I'm coming over to R from Stata and have a simple syntax question that I haven't been able to solve. I'm trying to loop across multiple currencies (GBP EUR JPY) to make an exchange rate adjustment. For each record denominated in one of the currencies listed above, set "amount_usd" equal to "amount" divided by the exchange rate (USDGBP, USDEUR, USDJPY).

Create data:

```
df <- data.frame(currency = c("GBP", "GBP", "EUR", "EUR", "JPY"), 
                 amount = c(100, 200, 100, 200, 100), 
                 USDGBP = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), 
                 USDEUR = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1), 
                 USDJPY = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100))

df$amount_usd <- df$amount
```

I tried various versions of the for loop below, but without any luck. I'd appreciate pointers on (1) proper loop syntax, and (2) tips for making the code more elegant.

```
df$face_value_curr_usd <- df$face_value_curr

for (curr in c("GBP", "EUR", "JPY")) {
    if (df[,which(colnames(df) == "currency")] == curr) {
        df[,which(colnames(df) == "amount_usd")] <-
            df[, which(colnames(df) == "amount")] / df[,which(colnames(df) == c("USD",curr))]
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

The resultant df$amount_usd should take on the values:

```
c(66.67, 133.33, 90.91, 181.82, 1)
```

Comment: Please could you paste in the result of `dput(head(df))`

Comment: A reproducible example and a desired output would be useful.

Comment: Expected output also needed

Comment: Now amended with expected output.

Answer (score 4):

What you really want are *vectorized* operations instead of loops. The idea is to subset the part of the data you want to modify using row indexing, and then do all of the computing at once on that.

First of all, you don't need to reference columns numerically. Instead of

```
df[,which(colnames(df) == "currency")]
```

you can just use

```
df[, "currency"]
```

or it's alias with the `$` operator

```
df$currency
```

You can use a vector to identify which rows of your data frame match a given value

```
gbp_rows <- df$currency == "GBP"
```

and you can use *that* to assign new values to only those rows, something like

```
df$face_value_curr_usd[gbp_rows] <- df$amount[gbp_rows] / df$fxGBP[gbp_rows]
```

Although I have to think that `fxGBP` is a constant, correct? So maybe something like this will do?

```
df$face_value_curr_usd[gbp_rows] <- df$amount[gbp_rows] / fxGBP
```

As has been commented, a reproducible version of your problem would be helpful, I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do.

EDIT: A combination of what I said and Cris's answer now that we have a `df`:

```
 df <- data.frame(currency = c("GBP", "GBP", "EUR", "EUR", "JPY"), 
                 amount = c(100, 200, 100, 200, 100), 
                 USDGBP = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), 
                 USDEUR = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1), 
                 USDJPY = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100))

for(curr in unique(df$currency)) {
  this_curr_rows <- df$currency == curr
  df$amount_usd[this_curr_rows] <- df$amount[this_curr_rows] / df[this_curr_rows, paste0("USD", curr)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, the solution worked well for one currency. My bigger concern is that I want to execute the same set of commands for all currencies. If I wanted to generate "gbp_rows" vectors for multiple currencies, the Stata syntax would be something akin to: "foreach curr in gbp eur jpy { gen `curr'_gbp = (currency == "`curr'")}". How would I similarly reference the looped item in R syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Using this data:

```
df <- data.frame(currency = c("GBP", "GBP", "EUR", "EUR", "JPY"), 
                 amount = c(100, 200, 100, 200, 100), 
                 USDGBP = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), 
                 USDEUR = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1), 
                 USDJPY = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100))
```

You can do:

```
for(curr in unique(df$currency)){
  df[paste("amount_usd",curr,sep="-")]=df$amount/df[paste("USD",curr, sep="")]
}
```

Which produce this results:

```
currency    amount  USDGBP  USDEUR  USDJPY  amount_usd-GBP  amount_usd-EUR  amount_usd-JPY
GBP 100 1.5 1.1 100 66.7    90.9    1
GBP 200 1.5 1.1 100 133.3   181.8   2
EUR 100 1.5 1.1 100 66.7    90.9    1
EUR 200 1.5 1.1 100 133.3   181.8   2
JPY 100 1.5 1.1 100 66.7    90.9    1
```

So its gives you the exchange rate adjustment for all your currencies.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, very elegant! Is there a simple way to combine the resulting output in one variable rather than individually for each currency?

Comment: `df$amount_usd <- df$amount/df[paste0("USD", curr)]`

Comment: That method ends up rewriting df$amount_usd each time. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, sorry responded too fast. A combination of the two answers are what is needed here.

Comment: Added to my answer, upvoting Cris for team effort.